# How to auto-populate when checked / remove info when unchecked

Tags: javascript

I am very new to programming and I need some help.  I am making a billing/invoice program.  I would like to be able to populate and unpopulated an invoice by checking or unchecking a company and either one or multiple services.  The company names and services are being stored in a database.  I know this needs to be done with JavaScript.  I have been looking for examples of how to do this on the internet and I can't find anything that use checkboxes. I'm probably making this way harder than what it should be.  Any help on how I can do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Start by creating some HTML, CSS, storing stuff in database, than, on some button click go for that ID data into the database. Populate the returned JSON into your invoice fields. All this *communication* can be done using AJAX. Now, it depends what you want to use as backend, but you really should show some code. Please take a [tour], read [ask], than  when you have a specific problem create a [mcve] and ask for help. Welcome to Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

Google's first result on "javascript checkbox" is an answer to your struggle [(w3schools link)](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_display_checkbox_text.asp).

Answer (score 0):

you need to do it in few steps 
 1st. If data is stored in SQL database use PHP to transfer data for json or use PHP to insert data stright in to columns(checkbox labels)

2nd. Data is readable, so lest go for next step if you using JSON insert data in to your label's.
3rd. Write some code in JS, you need to create few functions like get checkbox val, load invoice , and some more relative to your case. 
 For sure you will have some trouble with writing code, but you have community, and we are here to help :D
 Good luck